# Why does my getpwent() call return the wrong user?

Tags: perl

I always forget how to do this in Perl.
Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @got = getpwent();
my $username    = ${[getpwent()]}[0];

print Dumper( @got );
print "username is [$username]\n";
```

... and here is the output it produces ...

```
$VAR1 = 'root';
$VAR2 = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$VAR3 = 0; 
$VAR4 = 0;
$VAR5 = ''; 
$VAR6 = '';
$VAR7 = 'myhost root';
$VAR8 = '/root';
$VAR9 = '/bin/bash';
username is [bin]
```

... and my question is, why is username equal 'bin' instead of 'root'?

Comment: Post the code for `getpwent()`.

Comment: The `Dumper` method takes a reference to the array as such `\@got`.

Comment: @Jack Maney - `getpwent` is a builtin function

Comment: Also, `${[getpwent()]}[0];` would more commonly be written `(getpwent())[0]`.

Comment: @mob - Huh. So it is. My mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It iterates over users; you're calling it twice, and getting information for two users.

```
$ perl -E 'say $foo while $foo = getpwent()'
root
daemon
bin
sys
sync
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Repeated calls to `getpwent` return different rows in your password file (or whatever source of user information `getpwent` is using).

`root` is the first user listed in your password file, `bin` is the second.

Call `endpwent` to reset the iterator and replicate your previous calls to `getpwent`:

```
for (0..2) {
    print scalar getpwent(), "\n";
}
print "-- reset --\n";
endpwent();
for (0..3) {
    print scalar getpwent(), "\n";
}
```

outputs (YMMV)

```
SYSTEM
LocalService
NetworkService
-- reset --
SYSTEM
LocalService
NetworkService
Administrators
```